Loss returned by .fit() not equivalent to loss printed by verbose (Tensorflow)
I am trying to train a Tensorflow Recommenders model and I was surprised to see, that the training loss returned by the fit() method does not match the numbers for the losses printed to the console.
The first image shows what is printed during model training. We can see that that loss and total loss start at nearly 7000. But, when I later check the dictionary returned after fitting we can see a total_loss starting at around 400 (see second image).
Validation loss on the other hand seems to match  to what was printed during training.
How can that be?
# Fitting
model = RecommendationModel(output_layer_size=output_layer_size, hidden_layer_sizes=hidden_layer_sizes)
model.compile(run_eagerly=False,
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.legacy.Adagrad(learning_rate=learning_rate)) # 0.001

model_fitted = model.fit(
        x=cached_train,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=True,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        validation_data=cached_val,
        callbacks=[
            tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
                monitor='val_loss',  
                patience=1,          
                min_delta=1.0,
                mode='min',
                ),
            ]
    )





What method are you talking about? And what are the exact numbers that do not match? That is not clear to me from the question.

Where does your loss come from? You compile without loss..

to me they both look the same, the first snapshot jumps from epoch 23 to epoch 29, other than that the numbers don't seem to be different. Can you specifically point to the difference?

@mhenning The loss of the Tensorflow Recommenders library is  categorical cross entropy (Retrieval, not ranking)

@Zain I added some better images. Previously, I did not  have a better way to show what I meant. Now we can see that what is printed by the fit() method is not equal to the values contained in the dictionary returned after training.

@vossi what is you TensorFlow version? can you repeat your experiment with an updated TensorFlow version and see if you see the same behavior? In older versions, these two values were aggregated and last batch loss values over each epoch.

Now all the code is gone. Please show how you construct the model. Images alone are not that helpful.

AFter the update, we can see that the the first total loss and tenth example is:
Example batch 1:
6885.1498/409.361328125 = 16.819
Example Batch 10:
5520.1580/325.178955078125 = 16.975
Is this somewhere close to the batch size you are using? The reason I am asking is that the loss needs to be divided by your batch size.
Previous answer before update:
What is happening when fitting and logging out the loss is that the code rounds and clips numbers before writing to the console.
What does this mean?
e.g. 67.88265991210938 becomes
67.8827
This means that they are indeed the same numbers, but just with lower precision.

I added some different images. At the time of writing, I didnt have a better model to show what I meant. Last time, the values for total_loss were different to the values for loss. Now we can clearly see the difference between what is returned and what is printed.

How big are your batches?
